# Expected null to be truthy. Jasmine / Karma

Tags: jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my component injected into a mock class I created. Although the component works when I try to test its existence it returns null.

Injectable Component:

```
import { Injectable, ElementRef, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NgBackdropComponent {
  private renderer: Renderer2;
  private appElementRef: ElementRef;

  message: string = 'Carregando...';

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    this.appElementRef = new ElementRef(<Element>document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0));
  }

  show() {
    const divSpinnerItem1 = this.renderer.createElement('i');
    const divSpinnerItem2 = this.renderer.createElement('i');
    const divSpinnerItem3 = this.renderer.createElement('i');
    const divSpinner = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(divSpinner, 'spinner');
    this.renderer.appendChild(divSpinner, divSpinnerItem1);
    this.renderer.appendChild(divSpinner, divSpinnerItem2);
    this.renderer.appendChild(divSpinner, divSpinnerItem3);

    const spanMensagem = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    spanMensagem.innerHTML = this.message;

    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(div, 'lock-content');
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, divSpinner);
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, spanMensagem);

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.appElementRef.nativeElement, div);
  }

  hide() {
    const elemento = this.appElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.lock-content');
    if (elemento) {
      elemento.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

my testing environment:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NgBackdropComponent } from './ng-backdrop.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="clickButton()"></button>
    `
})
class MockNgBackdropComponent {
  constructor(private backdrop: NgBackdropComponent) { }

  clickButton() {
    this.backdrop.message = 'Teste BackDrop aesdas';
    this.backdrop.show();
    console.log('iniciei backdrop');
  }

  closeBackdrop() {
    this.backdrop.hide();
  }
}

describe('NgBackdropComponent', () => {
  let component: MockNgBackdropComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockNgBackdropComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MockNgBackdropComponent],
      providers: [NgBackdropComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockNgBackdropComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  describe('Deve injetar', async () => {

    it('Deve ter uma div principal', function () {
      const btnClick = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
      btnClick.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.lock-content');
      console.log(el);

      expect(el).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

In testing I create a Mock class where I inject my component.
I do not understand why it can not find the class because it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find it in the component is because you did not create it in the component.  If you look at this line in your constructor:

```
this.appElementRef = new ElementRef(<Element>document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0))
```

You are creating it on the document directly in the `<body>` element.  If you search for that in your spec, you will find it there.  I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53306330?file=app%2Fng-backdrop.component.spec.ts) to show you what I mean.  Here is the spec from that stackblitz:

```
it('Deve ter uma div principal', () => {
  const btnClick = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  console.log(btnClick);
  btnClick.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const appElementRef = new ElementRef(<Element>document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0));
  const el = appElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.lock-content');
  expect(el).toBeTruthy();
});
```

---

#### Adding a little more clarification:

If you `console.log(appElementRef)` you'll notice that its tagName is `body`, and note the contents of its nativeElement.innerHTML Here is what that would look like "prettyfied":

```
<body>
    <div class="jasmine_html-reporter">
        <div class="jasmine-banner"><a class="jasmine-title" href="http://jasmine.github.io/" target="_blank"></a><span
                class="jasmine-version">3.3.0</span></div>
        <ul class="jasmine-symbol-summary"></ul>
        <div class="jasmine-alert"></div>
        <div class="jasmine-results">
            <div class="jasmine-failures"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nprogress" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="bar" role="bar" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px); transition: all 200ms ease 0s;">
            <div class="peg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="root0" ng-version="7.0.1">
        <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class="lock-content">
        <div class="spinner">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
        </div>
        <span>Teste BackDrop aesdas</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note how the button was created within the div with `id="root0"`?  However, the div with `class="lock-content"` was created right off the root `<body>` element, and therefore is not within the div of the component.

In fact, you can see this very clearly when you `console.log(fixture.nativeElement)` and see that the tagName is "div", its innerHTML is `<button></button>`, and it has two attributes: `id: "root0"` and `ng-version: "7.0.1"`.  Put that all together and it looks like this:

```
<div id="root0" ng-version="7.0.1">
    <button></button>
</div>
```

So you can clearly see that you cannot find the div you created in the component because you created it outside the component.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DebugElement, for example:

```
it('Deve ter uma div principal', function () {
  const btnClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
  btnClick.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.lock-content'));
  console.log(el);

  expect(el).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Follow [this link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/components/) for more information.